# How to save registers from one MIPS program from another MIPS program?

Tags: assembly, stack, mips, cpu-registers

I am running two MIPS programs together, one which branches onto a different program and runs that. I want the program being run initially to save registers from the program that it's branching to.

Example:

**test.s**

```
.text

main:
addi $t0, $t0, 1
addi $t1, $t1, 2
addi $s0, $s0, 3
addi $s1, $s1, 4
jr $ra
```

**jump.s**

```
.text
    .globl saveRegs

saveRegs: 
jal     main            # jumps to test.s main
????
li      $v0, 10
syscall
```

What would be the method to save registers $t0, $t1, $s0, $s1, and possibly any additional registers only using code that could be written in jump.s? Would these registers be saved to the stack in jump.s and if so, how could I do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "saving" the registers. For what purpose? The very next thing you do in your code is to terminate the program.

Comment: If I did, say "add $t1, $t1, $t0" in jump.s where the "????" is, would I be doing 2+1  ($t0 + $t1 using the values of $t0 and $t1 from test.s), or would I be doing 0+0 ($t0 + $t1 using the values of $t0 and $t1 from jump.s) since $t0 and $t1 in jump.s have 0 as a value? If it's the case of the latter, how could I make it so that it uses test.s's values for $t0 and $t1 while the code itself is written in jump.s, or simply, how would jump.s get access to the register values of test.s?

Comment: Why don't you just test it and see what happens? That seems like the fastest way forward.

Comment: If you put both pieces of code in the same program so they can call each other, they're not separate programs anymore.  They're just functions inside one program.  At which point you need a "calling convention" which defines which registers callees should look in for their args, and thus which registers callers should put those args in.  And other stuff like that so they don't step on each other's toes.

Comment: Oh, I think you just want to snapshot architectural state after `main` exits.  So write a bunch of `sw` instructions to store them to the stack, or to an array in .data